# Advanced Jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css

Just wondering is it possible to create something like this animation but in jquery?

http://www.a-cero.com/

This is what I've come up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/326/

Comment: Just the animation so the way the logo appears and the type writing animation

Comment: [jQuery is awesome and do all things!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/186879) jQuery + HTML5 should be able to do something similar, if not better. Now show us some effort in trying to reproduce it and ask when you get stuck. =]

Comment: This is what I've come up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/326/

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on your own question, it seems my initial answer was not what you were looking for. You could perhaps try combining one of the numerous reflection plugins for jQuery with `.slideDown()`? Here's something to get you started:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <button>slide it</button>
  <div class="inner">Slide from bottom</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
}
.slide .inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slidebottom button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

*Source: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions*

**Numerous reflection plugins (from Google):**

- http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQReflect/
- http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery
- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins:reflect
- http://cow.neondragon.net/stuff/reflection/

**A guide!**

- http://davidwalsh.name/javascrip-reflection

Comment: Wow thanks for this mate! Will have a play and post the finished product